# Combine two request into one using laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two table email (email_id, email) and users (user_id) with a pivot table user_email (id, user_id, email_id) and i would like to check the existence of my email "toto@toto.com" for my user_id "2".

```
$emailID = Email::where('email', 'toto@toto.com')->pluck('id');
$exists = User::find('2')->emails->contains($emailID);
```

The result is ok, but i would like to know if it's possible to combine this into one query using Eloquent.

If have these models :

```
class Email extends Model {
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_email');
    }
}

class User extends Model {
    public function emails() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Email', 'user_email');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make query with relationships too:

```
$email_address = 'toto@toto.com';
$user_id = 2;

$email = Email::whereHas('users', function($q) use ($user_id) {
    $q->where('users.id', $user_id);
})->where('email', $email_address)->first();

if($email->exists) {
    //... it exists
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it like this.

```
public function getUserById($id) {
    $user = User::with('emails')->where('id', 2)->first();

    return view('your-view')->with('user', $user);
}
```

Then on your blade template.

```
@foreach ($user->emails as $email) 
    {{ $email->email }}<br/>
@endforeach
```

Check out the [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) documentation for more information.